# laravel-echo-server - Client can not be authenticated, got HTTP status 403 JWT auth

Tags: laravel, socket.io, laravel-echo

I am building a SPA. I am using laravel for backend and vuejs for front end. They are running independently on different port. (Using laravel api)

- Laravel is running on 8000
- Vue is running on 8082

I am allowing user to authenticate using JWT Auth.

I am trying to make a real time data transfer application using **laravel-echo-server** and have used public channel to transfer data and this worked great.

Now I need to use private channel to broadcast data to authenticated user and that's where I am not able to figure out how to make it work and I am getting error such as

```
NuG9yhe46E3N9Q6zAAAA could not be authenticated to private-some-p
rivate-channel

Client can not be authenticated, got HTTP status 403
```

here is laravel-echo-server.json file

```
{
    "authHost": "http://localhost:8000",
    "authEndpoint": "/broadcasting/auth",
    "clients": [
        {
            "appId": "mprimeapp",
            "key": "d8f6639653d0c4f31efa56d27f6ab502"
        }
    ],
    "database": "redis",
    "databaseConfig": {
        "redis": {
            "port": "6379",
            "host": "127.0.0.1"
        },
        "sqlite": {
            "databasePath": "/database/laravel-echo-server.sqlite"
        }
    },
    "devMode": true,
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": "8890",
    "protocol": "http",
    "socketio": {},
    "sslCertPath": "",
    "sslKeyPath": "",
    "sslCertChainPath": "",
    "sslPassphrase": "",
    "apiOriginAllow": {
        "allowCors": true,
        "allowOrigin": ["http://localhost:8000", "http://localhost:8082"],
        "allowMethods": "GET, POST",
        "allowHeaders": "Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Authorization, X-CSRF-TOKEN, X-Socket-Id"
    }
}
```

I am using redis not sqlite database that is running also.

My main.js file vue app

```
const tokenData = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('authUser'))
if (tokenData !== null) {

  window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'socket.io',
    host: 'http://localhost:8890',
    auth: {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + tokenData.token
      }
    }
  })
}

window.Echo.private('some-private-channel')
  .listen('SomeEvent', (e) => {
    console.log(e)
  })
```

here are feew things that i wanted to ask.

1. authEndpoint in laravel-echo-server.json file, how does it work? do i have to make an end point in my api.php file to authenticate user.
2. clients array in laravel-echo-server.json file, what is use of data inside it?

In Laravel app inside config/app.php

I have this line uncommented  `App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class`

In BroadcastServiceProvider.php

```
 public function boot()
    {
        Broadcast::routes([ 'middleware' => [ 'auth:jwt.auth' ] ] ]);
        require base_path('routes/channels.php');
    }
```

**UPDATE**

It seems like there is something wrong with above function. To be more specific thing thing `[ 'middleware' => [ 'api', 'jwt.auth' ] ]`

Getting this error after changing middlware array

```
[15:58:13] - vAKK8BO7vs2TZy4SAAAA could not be authenticated to private-some-private-channel
{
    "message": "Auth guard [jwt.auth] is not defined.",
    "exception": "InvalidArgumentException",
    "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\mipm-l\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Auth\\AuthManag
er.php",
.....
.....
.....
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed and configured a JWT Auth package https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth ? (Sorry but you did not mention)
Also make sure you have following lines in your Kernel.php

```
   protected $routeMiddleware = [
    ...
    'jwt.auth' => \Tymon\JWTAuth\Middleware\GetUserFromToken::class,
    'jwt.refresh' => \Tymon\JWTAuth\Middleware\RefreshToken::class,
    ...
    ];
```